# "a bewildering amount of choice" or "a bewildering amount of choices"?

Tags: nouns, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

"a bewildering amount of choice" is a sentence from a dictionary. I think it should be ""a bewildering amount of choices" and I found both of them can be found from the Internet. Anyone can help to clarify please? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "a bewildering amount of choice" is a sentence from a dictionary. I think it should be ""a bewildering amount of choices"

'choice' is one of those English words that can be countable or uncountable. We normally use 'amount' with uncountable nouns and 'number' with countable ones.

**Examples**

A large amount of sugar. (uncountable)

A large amount of choice (uncountable)

A large number of cows (countable)

A large number of choices (countable)

**Afterthought**

On consideration I sympathise with your point of view. It is not entirely clear to me what an amount of choice refers to. It's not obvious how you would quantify it, e.g. 'Mary has 2.5 as much choice as John' doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: Are you sure choice is uncountable?  Can you give some sentences in which choice is used in an uncountable way?

Comment: @michael_timofeev - How about the one that the OP gave 'from a dictionary'.

Comment: well, I'm a bit of a skeptic, so just because it comes from a dictionary doesn't mean it's right.  I'm sure I'm going to be pilloried for that statement but I have seen dictionary definitions that make me say "what?!"  I don't know, Chasley...I was looking at some entries just now and I can't seem to grasp how it's uncountable or how we can use "amount."  Maybe it's a BrE thing.

Comment: I don't think it is British. How about - "Choice  is something that we all like to have in our lives." versus "We all like to have choices in life." I think that gives the distinction pretty clearly.

Comment: maybe we should be saying "a lot of" as a counter and not amount.  I thought amount was for volumes of things like sugar, tea, water.  Of course, we say "amount of money."